# Eclipse Luna SWT version

Tags: eclipse, swt

¿Is there a way to know the version of SWT that it was used to develop a certain version of Eclipse?.

I only could find an SWT version on the Plug-ins tab of the Eclipse Installation Details, but I am not sure if that is the SWT used to run Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. The plug-in with the id `org.eclipse.swt` is indeed the version of SWT that runs Eclipse.